# Which systems have 'pager' shortcut/alias?

Tags: less, pager, more

On a Debian system, one can type `pager` in order to use whatever pager program happens to be default/available. By default, `less` is used, and if not available, the lesser `more` gets to do the job. Is such a thing available in other Unix and Linux systems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unix tradition is for applications that want to call a pager to call **`$PAGER`**, i.e. use the contents of the environment variable `PAGER` as a command name. (Whether shell metacharacters are expanded in `$PAGER` is not consistent between applications.) The unix tradition further uses `more` if the `PAGER` variable is not set. There is a similar tradition for text editors: use `$EDITOR` (or, for historical reasons, `$VISUAL`), falling back to `vi`.

Having a command named `pager` is specific to Debian (and derivatives, including Ubuntu). `/usr/bin/pager` is in fact a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/pager`, which points to the the “best” available pager (the Debian maintainers decide which is best, and the system administrator can override their choice), using the [alternatives](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) framework.

Debian also provides `/usr/bin/sensible-pager`. This script runs `$PAGER` if the variable is set, and falls back to `pager` otherwise. Its purpose is to be used in programs where a single pager path has to be hard-coded. This behavior is documented in the [Debian policy manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s11.4).

Comment: Just as an addendum, while not included by default, a `pager` generic could be used by the alternative system that is found in Red Hat derivatives such as Fedora.  Also, if one really wanted to, I'll bet one could implement such a system on other Unixes since I've seen alternative frameworks implemented in perl.

Comment: @Steven: It's [not surprising](http://lists.debian.org/debian-curiosa/2002/06/msg00000.html) that Red Hat's alternatives look like Debian's. And the framework *is* implemented as a Perl script (`/usr/bin/update-alternatives`) — [or was](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/05/27/rewriting-update-alternatives-in-c/).

Comment: [POSIX specifies that `man` shall interpret `$PAGER` as an string passed to `sh -c`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/man.html). So at least `man` recognises metachars in `$PAGER`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ update-alternatives --list pager
/bin/less
/bin/more
/usr/bin/pg
/usr/bin/w3m
```

YMMV depending on what you have installed, but this is Debian-specific (well, and derivatives too).

Customarily one uses `$PAGER` with a fallback to `more`.

Answer (score 1):

All Linux-Distributions I have used so far (Gentoo, Debian, Slackware, Fedora, OpenSuse) had an Environment-Variable called PAGER which set the pager (default, as said, less). 
It's set in your shell environment.
I think the command `man` uses this variable..